# Recommended way to export variables in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, export

I have a `worker.js` file which periodically updates the values of few variables.
In other files of my Node.js server I want to access to those vars.

I know how to export them, but it seems they are exported by value - i.e. they have the value they had at the moment I issued the `require` function.

Of course, I'm interested to access to their latest value.
What's the recommended way to do this? A "getter" function or else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible way to export them by reference is to actually manipulate the `module.exports` object - like so:

```
//worker.js
module.exports.exportedVar = 1;
var byValueVar = 2;

setInterval(foo, 2000);

function foo() {
    module.exports.exportedVar = 6;
    x = 8;
}

//otherfile.js
var worker = require('./worker');
console.log(worker.exportedVar); //1
console.log(worker.byValueVar) //2

setInterval(foo, 3000);

function foo() {
    console.log(worker.exportedVar); //6
    console.log(worker.byValueVar); //2
}
```

Comment: As far as I understand, it's not a way to export them *by reference*, but we're going to "re-export" them every time their value has changed. Or, in other words, I don't have a local copy of the var, but I'm working directly on the "exported" one. It's a good/recommended pratice?

Comment: Well, if those vars are just for exporting purposes then it's definitely fine. if it's for internal use also, maybe getter function is the more correct approach